# combine big text files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I have a bunch of text files that have the next format

```
word(1) num(1,1) num(1,2) num(1,3) ... num(1,300)
word(2) num(2,1) num(2,2) num(2,3) ... num(2,300)
word(3) num(3,1) num(3,2) num(3,3) ... num(3,300)
...
word(n) num(n,1) num(n,2) num(n,3) ... num(n,300)
```

The name of the files is palabrasX.txt where X is a number that represents the length of the strings that makes the words inside the files (which go from 1 to 32), so for example if the word is "cat" then should be inside palabras3.txt

Then the real problem is that some of these files are too big to open by normal means, and I want to make one big file that has all the information of these files, so I would have all the words with 1 character first then all the words with 2 and so on until 32

I'm trying something like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
filenames = {}
for i in range(32):
    filenames[i]="palabras"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    with open("VectoresPalabrasEspañol\TodasMisPalabras.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

but it stays in a working state, so I'm not sure if I have a problem with the logic, or if I triggered an infinite loop or something else.

by the way, the path for the full file is:

```
"VectoresPalabrasEspañol\TodasMisPalabras.txt"
```

and the path for the palabraX.txt is:

```
f"palabras\Probables palabras\palabras{length}.txt"
```

Comment: ***files are too big to open by normal means,***: Read up on [sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3) which allows `SELECT * WHERE word_len = x`, `x` are in the range `1 - 32`.

Comment: ***if I triggered an infinite loop or something else***: Add a `print(fname)` right after `for fname in ...` to see what you get.

Comment: the for fname in prints "palabras1.txt","palabras2.txt", and so on until 32

Comment: after trying the code in the answer that has been given by @safiqulislam I realized that the real problem is that `filenames[i]` should have the string of the full path to the file, not only the name of the file

Comment: ***prints "palabras1.txt","palabras2.txt", and so on until 32***: This couldn't be the case! You get the `dict` **key** value wich is: `0 0 1 0 1 2 0 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can code this way

here file path is current directory

```
import os

filenames = []

for i in range(32):
    filenames.append("palabras"+str(i+1)+".txt")

with open("TodasMisPalabras.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for fname in filenames:
            # fname=fname[1]
            if os.path.exists(fname):
                with open(fname) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: The OP wants to sort ***"all the words with 1 character first then all the words with 2 and so on until 32"***. Where did your example fulfill this?

Comment: @stovfl if i understand the question ans is...... filenames array contains sorted ('palabras1.txt','palabras2.txt',......) after appending all file names....... so in the filenames loop while writing 'palabras1.txt' file data will be written first to the one big file and so on

Comment: **Every** file contains `word(1), word(2), word(n)` and the OP wants in the big file: `word(1), word(1), word(1) ...` from all 32 files followd by `word(2), word(2), word(2) ...` and so on.

Comment: I have a silly question, does the comment in your code has an actual role?, lately, I found out that some comments act like active code like the # encoding: utf-8

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias no you can remove that

Comment: also after trying this code I realize that the problem was that the `filenames` needed the full string of the path to work, not only the name of the file inside the folder so I changed your sixth line of code for `filenames.append("palabras\Probables palabras\palabras"+str(i+1)+".txt")` and works just as I wanted

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias yes you are right....i mentioned.... i tested with current directory

Comment: @safiqulIslam I was trying to use a dictionary, but I think your solution it's better. thanks for your answer